# Assigning the value of an union containing structures to NULL in c programming

Tags: c, struct

I have a union and 2 structures in the following format and I need to set one of them to NULL.
For example m = NULL or t = NULL;

```
 typedef struct
 {
    char *population;
   char *area;

 } metropolitan;


 typedef struct
 {
    char *airport;
    char *type;

 } tourist;


 typedef union
 {
     tourist t;
     metropolitan m;
 } ex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tourist` and `metropolitan` are `struct`s, you cannot assign `NULL` to them.

But, if you declare like

```
typedef union
{
    tourist* t;
    metropolitan* m;
} ex;
```

you can do

```
ex e;
e.t=NULL; //which makes e.m=NULL as well
```

Comment: Is there any way without declaring tourist and metropolitan as pointers ?

Comment: @yogisha Since the memory positions of the variables in a `union` overlap, I don't think there will be any other way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the members of your union are not pointers, so it doesn't make all that much sense setting the value to `NULL`.

Second, the way a union works is that if you set one of the members, you set the others as well. More precisely, all members of a union have the address, but different types. I.e. the different types gives you a way to interpret the same area in memory as multiple types at once.

To differentiate from a strutct:

```
struct a {
    unsigned b;
    char *c;
};
```

In this case, the appropriate number of bytes are allocated for each of the fields `a` and `s`, one after the other.

```
union a {
    unsigned b;
    char *c;
};
```

Here, the values of `b` and `c` are stored in the same address. I.e. if you're setting `a.b` to `0`, a readout from `a.c` would give `NULL` (numeric `0x0`).

Comment: I dont want it to equal NULL necessarily. I want to make sure that if one of the variables in the union contains a value the other is equal to null . I don't want to use MALLOC and allocate memory to the variables inside the union ,that is why I did not declare them as pointers.

Comment: @yogisha With unions ALL members overlap in the same memory space.  You can't set one member to NULL and expect the other to have a valid address.

Comment: @yogisha I don't think you understand how unions work. See my example, or read more here about structures and unions: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html

Comment: I understand now, they share the same memory so i cant have one NULL without ruining the other.Would it be right if I clear the address before assigning a value to a particular variable correct?

Answer (score 1):

With unions you need to tell them apart.

So define a structure thus:

```
typedef enum { MET, TOURIST} Chap;

typedef struct {

   Chap human;
   union {
       tourist t;
       metropolitan m;
   }
} Plonker;
```

Then you know what is what an then set the appropriate values

i.e

```
Plonker p;
p.human = MET;
p.m.population = NULL;
... etc
```